# Parse arbitrarily large JSON array in Rust

Tags: json, parsing, rust, serde

Let's say we have a JSON document where one of the properties is an arbitrarily large array of objects:

```json
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
      {"type": "feature", ...},
      {"type": "feature", ...},
      ... many, many more objects ...
    ]
}
```

The document might even be sent over the network so the number of objects inside the array might be unknown in advance.

The document might be several gigabytes large.

How can I parse such a document in Rust (preferably with Serde) without loading it into memory first? I'm only interested in the objects in the array. The ‘parent’ object (if you will) can be ignored.

Comment: You say you're only interested in the objects in the array, but that looks like nearly all the data. Did you try anything yet? Does `from_reader` do what you want? Did you create a type to deserialize it into?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `features` array is reasonably close to the "top" of your JSON structure (i.e. only a single level down), you can reasonably do this with serde.

The sad part is that the usual `#[derive(Deserialize)]` mechanic usually can't be used on the outer levels of your JSON structure, because you typically need some kind of state to process your stream of features, but the derived deserializers are stateless. So you must implement two `DeserializeSeed`.

The first replaces what would be the `#[derive(Deserialize)]` on your outer struct, but calls `next_value_seed` instead of `next_value` on `features`. This is all boilerplate, and I' still waiting for someone to add this to serde's derive macros:

```
struct FeatureCollectionStream<F>(F);
impl<'de, F: FnMut(Feature)> DeserializeSeed<'de> for FeatureCollectionStream<F> {
    type Value = ();

    fn deserialize<D>(self, d: D) -> Result<Self::Value, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        return d.deserialize_struct("FeatureCollection", &["type", "features"], FCV(self.0));
        struct FCV<F>(F);
        impl<'de, F: FnMut(Feature)> Visitor<'de> for FCV<F> {
            type Value = ();

            fn visit_map<A: MapAccess<'de>>(mut self, mut map: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error> {
                while let Some(k) = map.next_key::<String>()? {
                    match k.as_str() {
                        "type" => {
                            map.next_value::<String>()?;
                        }
                        "features" => map.next_value_seed(FeatureStream(&mut self.0))?,
                        s => return Err(todo!()),
                    }
                }
                Ok(())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The next serializer is the one you actually want, the one that processes the sequence of `Feature` as a stream:

```
struct FeatureStream<F>(F);
impl<'de, F: FnMut(Feature)> DeserializeSeed<'de> for FeatureStream<F> {
    type Value = ();

    fn deserialize<D>(self, d: D) -> Result<Self::Value, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        return d.deserialize_seq(FV(self.0));
        struct FV<F>(F);
        impl<'de, F: FnMut(Feature)> Visitor<'de> for FV<F> {
            type Value = ();

            fn visit_seq<A: serde::de::SeqAccess<'de>>(
                mut self,
                mut seq: A,
            ) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error> {
                while let Some(f) = seq.next_element()? {
                    (self.0)(f)
                }
                Ok(())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The cute part is that you can still use the derive magic for the inner structures.

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Default)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
enum FeatureType {
    #[default]
    Feature,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Default)]
struct Feature {
    #[allow(unused)]
    r#type: FeatureType,
    // ...   
}
```

Using this concoction:

```
FeatureCollectionStream(|f: Feature| todo!("Do something with each feature"))
    .deserialize(&mut serde_json::Deserializer::from_reader(x))?;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ddff5d6ca4b85acd4eae4091241ef768) with left-out error handling

(c.f. another [answer by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71326843/how-do-i-get-a-seqaccess-type-for-an-inner-sequence-of-a-serde-seqaccess/71333006#71333006) employing the same "trick")

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Struson](https://crates.io/crates/struson) and its [`serde` feature](https://docs.rs/struson/0.2.0/struson/serde/index.html) to achieve this:

First you would use `seek_to` to position the reader at the location in the JSON data where you want to read the JSON array. Then you would start the JSON array with `begin_array` and use `has_next` as loop condition to check if the array has more elements. In the loop you can then use `deserialize_next` to deserialize your Feature values.

```rust
let json = r#"
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
        {"type": "feature1"},
        {"type": "feature2"}
    ]
}
"#;
// `std::io::Read` providing the JSON data; in this example the str bytes
let reader = json.as_bytes();

#[derive(serde::Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Feature {
    r#type: String,
    // ...
}

let mut json_reader = JsonStreamReader::new(reader);

json_reader.seek_to(&json_path!["features"])?;
json_reader.begin_array()?;

while json_reader.has_next()? {
    let feature: Feature = json_reader.deserialize_next()?;
    // ... use deserialized value in some way
    println!("deserialized: {feature:?}")
}

// Optionally consume the remainder of the JSON document
json_reader.skip_to_top_level()?;
json_reader.consume_trailing_whitespace()?;
```

This is all performed in a streaming way by Struson, so it will only read as much data necessary to deserialize each of the Feature values (and possibly buffer some more bytes internally for the next call).

---

Disclaimer: I am the author of Struson, and currently it is still experimental (but feedback is highly appreciated!).