# How to deserialize and transcode arbitrary value type in Rust?

Tags: rust, serde

I am writing a proxy to transfer [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/) to HTTP protocol (using Rocket framework).

Since MessagePack is binary protocol and hard to show here, I display it in equivalent json format bellow.

The input

- if error: `{"error":{"label":123, "message":"invalid args"}}`, then I response HTTP_400 or HTTP_500 depending on the `error.label` field. This part is easy.
- if good: `{"result": … }`, where the `...` mean arbitrary value, which may be a string, an array or an arbitrary object. Then I response HTTP_200, with the body is the value of `result` in JSON format. I do not know how to do this part.

Is [Manually implementing Deserialize for a struct](https://serde.rs/deserialize-struct.html) the right answer where I should look into? But the example is not arbitrary value type.

---

Sorry that I did not explain my question clearly. I try to add some more explanation here.

I know how to deserialize fixed value type: to define a corresponding struct/enum and define `#[derive(Deserialize)]` on it.

I know how to transcode totally un-fixed value type: to use `serde-transcode` crate.

But now I need to deserialize *part* of the input: to deserialize the `error` field if any; but transcode the `result` field from MsgPack to Json, without knowing it's definition.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking, partly because we don't know what MessagePack implementation you're using.

Comment: Serde can actually do this. You just need to Serialize and Deserialize for an `enum`. By default, enums are externally tagged and differentiating between "result" and "error" should just work. More reading here: https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html. To parse the rest of the result object, you can just parse everything into an HashMap. If some of the values are known you can use `[serde(flatten)]` (example: https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/941#issuecomment-375486935).

Comment: Manually impelementing `Deserialize` for enums is difficult, better not to. Anything wrong with just `#[derive(Deserialize)] struct Message { #[serde(rename = "error")] Error { label: u32, message: String }, #[serde(rename = "result")] Result(serde_json::Value), }`?

Comment: First, the input is in MsgPack and I use `rmp_serde` to deserialize it, which does not have a `Value` type.
Second, I guess deserializing into a `Value` may cause many memory allocation for map type, while using serde-transcode does not. 
@Caesar

Comment: `rmp_serde` does have a [value type](https://docs.rs/rmpv/latest/rmpv/). But if you're going to output JSON, it's probably better to use the JSON value type. Using `serde-transcode` is possible with seeded deserialization, but it will be great fun…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't my first answer [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71326843/how-do-i-get-a-seqaccess-type-for-an-inner-sequence-of-a-serde-seqaccess/71333006#71333006), but smuggling data into a Deserializer always ends up extremely verbose for me.

So first some theory: You need a `Deserializer` per "data type" - JSON value of decided shape and level inside your data. In your case, there's three:

- The top level `{"error": …}` or `{"result": …}` needs custom enum deserializer
- The `…` in `error`: `{"label":123, "message":"invalid args"}` - This deserializer is easy, it can be derived.
- The `…` in `result` needs a deserializer that actually calls `serde_transcode`

Two deserializers need to be written by hand. For the top level deserializer, our goal is just to recognize whether we have `error` or `result`, and smuggle some data into the `result` deserializer. The data is going to be the target serializer `S` to place the result data in. The method of choice for smuggling data through deserializers is `DeserializeSeed`. This requires a whole bunch of boilerplate, the only "decision" we make in this code is to call `deserialize_map` (because the top level value is a `{ … }`):

```
struct TranscodingDeserializeMessageSeed<S> {
    target: S,
}

impl<'de, S: Serializer> DeserializeSeed<'de> for TranscodingDeserializeMessageSeed<S> {
    type Value = Result<(), Error>;

    fn deserialize<D>(self, deserializer: D) -> Result<Self::Value, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct V<S> {
            target: S,
        }
        impl<'de, S: Serializer> Visitor<'de> for V<S> {
            // ...
        }
        deserializer.deserialize_map(V {
            target: self.target,
        })
     }
}
```

The actual magic of deciding `result` or `error` happens inside the visitor implementation. If it is result, we hand `S` to the second manually implemented `DeserializeSeed` with `next_value_seed`:

```
fn visit_map<A>(self, mut map: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
where
    A: serde::de::MapAccess<'de>,
{
    match map.next_key()? {
        Some("error") => Ok(Err(map.next_value()?)),
        Some("result") => map
            .next_value_seed(TranscodeSeed {
                target: self.target,
            })
            .map(Ok),
        _ => Err(serde::de::Error::custom("Expected key error or result")),
    }
}
```

Now, we can finally hand of to `serde_transcode`:

```
struct TranscodeSeed<S> {
    target: S,
}

impl<'de, S: Serializer> DeserializeSeed<'de> for TranscodeSeed<S> {
    type Value = ();

    fn deserialize<D>(self, deserializer: D) -> Result<Self::Value, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        match serde_transcode::transcode(deserializer, self.target) {
            Ok(_) => Ok(()),
            Err(e) => Err(serde::de::Error::custom(format!(
                "Error while transcoding: {}",
                e
            ))),
        }
    }
}
```

The final piece of the puzzle is actually invoking the outer `DeserializeSeed`:

```
let mut extracted = vec![]; // I'll write to a vec, but you can use any (sync) writer, so you don't need to keep the entire message in memory.
let mut extract = serde_json::Serializer::new(&mut extracted);
let res = DeserializeSeed::deserialize(
    TranscodingDeserializeMessageSeed {
        target: &mut extract,
    },
    &mut de, // Assuming de is your MsgPack deserializer
);
```

[Explorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#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)

And this brings me to a question: Are you sure this is viable for you? It is guaranteed that no data is written to `S` if the message type is `error` or some other invalid type, even if it might feel a bit icky to construct a serializer and then rely on nothing being written through it. The problem is that if your MsgPack message starts out as a valid `result` message and then turns out to be invalid in the middle, you'll likewise produce a HTTP 200 with a JSON message cut in the middle (and `deserialize` returning `Err`).

Comment: Thanks so much for you detailed answer! This is hard for me, and I need some time to understand it. Considering the complexity of this answer, using JSON's `Value` type maybe a better solution.

Comment: For your last question, I'd like to describe my original project and purpose. I'm developing a high-performance service. It needs an HTTP API. But I do not want it to spend much performance on the protocol parsing/generating, so the real server's API is MsgPack, and there are some HTTP-proxies which transfer between MsgPack and HTTP. The HTTP-proxy can be deployed multiple instances, and do some jobs like req-limit, black-list. The original question is about the proxy.
Maybe the difference of performance is not significant of MsgPack, Json, and HTTP, so the protocol-transfer is not necessary.

Comment: Uh, I think this is questionable. You don't want to write a rate limiting proxy yourself. You could maybe use an existing reverse proxy (envoy or somesuch) and implement your msgpack→json thing as a (wasm) plugin. But I really wonder whether the added complexity, latency, and compute cost will be worth it. JSON writing is really fast with serde_json already, and you could even speed it up further with one of the simd json crates. (Similarly, [HTTP is light](https://seanmonstar.com/blog/hyper-v1/).) Build the simple solution first, and if that turns out too slow, you'll know where to optimize.

Comment: I didn't make it clear before. I did not write a rate-limiting proxy myself, while I was going to do the rate-limiting and protocol-transfer on Rocket or Axum. Also, I'm just planning the whole thing right now.  It has not been decided whether to actually use MsgPack. Thanks.

Comment: "on Rocket or Axum". That's what I was expecting. Still.